# Doctrine on PostgreSQL: how to select a row if a jsonb field with an array of values contains the passed value

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, jsonb

I'm on PostgreSQL.

I have a Doctrine entity `FruitEntity` that has, among the others, two fields:

- `id` the primary key, are alphanumeric `string`s (ex.: `apple`);
- `aliases` is a `jsonb` field and contain a list of alternative IDs: (ex.: `["orange","banana""cherry"]`

I want to select the row with ID = `apple` if I pass the value `banana`.

So, this is the `FruitRepository` class (I'm on Symfony):

```php
class FruitRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, FruitEntity::class);
    }

    public function myMethod(string $fruitName)
    {
        $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->select('f.id')
            ->andWhere('f.id = :fruitName')
            ->orWhere("JSON_EXTRACT(f.aliases, '$.:fruitName')")
            ->setParameter('fruitName', $fruitName)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getScalarResult();

        ...
    }
}
```

This code produces this DQL query:

```
SELECT f.id FROM App\Entity\FruitEntity f WHERE f.id = :fruitName OR JSON_EXTRACT(f.aliases, '$.:fruitName')
```

It is obviously wrong and the error that it produces is this

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

**How can I select the row with ID `apple` passing the value `orange` that is present in the `aliases` column?**

Answer (score -1):

Ok, in the end I solved in this way:

```php
        $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->select('f.id')
            ->andWhere('c.id = :fruitName')
            ->orWhere("JSONB_CONTAINS(f.aliases, '\"" . $fruitName . "\"') = true")
            ->setParameter('fruitName', $fruitName)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getScalarResult();
```

It seems that parameters are not transformed when using these functions.

Also note I used `JSONB_CONTAINS` instead of `JSON_EXTRACT`.

Just for reference, I obviously used [`scienta/doctrine-json-functions`](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions)